# MongoDB and Apache Spark projection

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-spark

When pulling a MongoDB collection into Apache Spark/Hadoop, is it possible to do a projection via MongoInputFormat to reduce the size of the dataset returned?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify the `mongo.input.fields` option while configuring the MongoDB Hadoop Connector:

```
val config = new Configuration()
config.set("mongo.input.uri", [Your URI])
config.set("mongo.input.query", [Your Query])
config.set("mongo.input.fields", "{column: 1}")
```

Refer to [the official MongoDB Documentations](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) for the projection's syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The [MongoDB Spark Connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/) supports [Aggregation Pipelines](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/python/aggregation). Aggregation pipelines include the [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator.

Using the example from the Aggregation pipelines link, you could do the following in Python.

```
{ "_id" : 1, "type" : "apple", "qty" : 5 }
{ "_id" : 2, "type" : "orange", "qty" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 3, "type" : "banana", "qty" : 15 }
```

```
uri = f'mongodb://{user}:{password}@{host}/{database}.{collection}'
pipeline = json.dumps({
    '$project': {
        'type': 1,
        }
    }
)
df = spark.read.format("mongo").option(
    "uri", uri
).option(
    "pipeline", pipeline
).load()
df.show()
```

```
+---+------+
|_id| type |
+---+------+
|1.0| apple|
|2.0|orange|
|3.0|banana|
+---+------+
```

Here `spark` is the SparkSession object.

I used similar code within an AWS Glue job to reduce a very complex document (deep and broad) into a simple association between a reference ID and a particular value in the document tree. Without the projection I had type conversion errors because of inconsistencies in the document schema.

Answer (score 0):

While Kent's answer is correct, there is a preferred method to do this:

```
MongoConfigUtil.setFields(Configuration conf, DBObject fields);
```

While this essentially performs the same action described in Kent's answer, your code wouldn't break in the case where the key that controls the projection (`mongo.input.fields`) would be changed in the future.
Also, this method supports passing both a JSON string or a DBObject as the 2nd parameter. So in case you choose to use a DBObject, you don't have to serialize it yourself to a JSON string - the `MongoConfigUtil` does the serialization by itself.